# Why the plot of same function is different in Mathematica and MATLAB

Tags: plotting, matlab

I need to create a log-log plot of the following function:

$$
f_k(v)=\frac{v^2\left[v^2/(k-3/2)+1\right]^{-k}\ \Gamma(k+1)}{k\sqrt{\pi(k-3/2)}\ \Gamma(k-1/2)}
$$

And the *Mathematica* code is

```
f1=((v^2/(k - 3/2) + 1)^-k Gamma[k + 1] v^2)/(k Sqrt[(k - 3/2) \[Pi]]
  Gamma[k - 0.5])
```

The plot given by *Mathematica*  is:
[image]

and the plot given by MATLAB is:
[image]

What could be the reason for this?
Please see the code of *Mathematica*?

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]

 distFunckappa = ((v^2/(k - 3/2) + 1)^-k Gamma[k + 1] v^2)/(
 k Sqrt[(k - 3/2) \[Pi]] Gamma[k - 0.5])



 k = 2;

LogLogPlot[distFunckappa, {v, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], AxesLabel -> {"v", "DNF"}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

and code in MATLAB is:

```
k=2;

v=0:0.1:10;

kappaDistFunc=(gamma(k+1)./(k.*gamma(k-1/2).*sqrt(k-3/2).*sqrt(pi))).*(1+(v.^2./(k-3/2))).^(-k).*v.^2;

loglog(kappaDistFunc)
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version are you using? on 11.3 I get similar plot as Matlab. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Mdh.png)

Comment: Mine is Mathematica 11.0. Did you use the same code, that I used?? Or did you made any changes

Comment: @Nasser If you see the plot that you got have almost the same shape, but both axes are totally different???

Comment: Your Matlab plot has x-values going from 2 to 100. The Mathematica plot has x-values going from about .01 to 10. If you plot them over the same raneg they will probably look more alike.

Comment: I see the problem in v11.0.0.0 but not in v11.0.1.0 Recommend that you download v11.0.1.0

Comment: @bills No sir, I have checked it by making the axis same.

Comment: @BobHanlon Why Mathematica 11.0 is not giving the correct answer

Comment: I have no way of knowing why the problem occurs in v11.0.0 but it has been fixed in v11.0 (specifically v11.0.1). Go to the [`User Portal`](https://user.wolfram.com/portal/login.html) and download v11.0.1

Comment: Your code runs well in my computer: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTkEh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTkEh.png)

Comment: @xinpei Which version of  mathematica that you use??

Comment: `LogLogPlot[((v^2/(k - 3/2) + 1)^(-k) Gamma[
      k + 1] v^2)/(k Sqrt[(k - 3/2) \[Pi]] Gamma[k - 1/2]) /. 
  k -> 2, {v, 0, 100}]` gives a similar plotting as of MATLAB, version 11.3.

Answer (score 4):

The two plots are not the same because the Matlab code doesn't plot $f_2(v)$ as a function of $v$, but as a function of the vector index.

In the code below I removed the 0 endpoint because in a log axis the 0 cannot be represented.

**Matlab**

```
v=0.1:0.1:10;

kappaDistFunc=(gamma(k+1)./(k.*gamma(k-1/2).*sqrt(k-3/2).*sqrt(pi))).*(1+(v.^2./(k-3/2))).^(-k).*v.^2;

loglog(v,kappaDistFunc); % The x-axis now represents v
```

[image: MAtlab plot]

**Mathematica**

```
distFunckappa = ((v^2/(k - 3/2) + 1)^-k Gamma[
      k + 1] v^2)/(k Sqrt[(k - 3/2) \[Pi]] Gamma[k - 0.5]);

k = 2;

LogLogPlot[distFunckappa, {v, 0.1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], AxesLabel -> {"v", "DNF"}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Still this code will not work in Mathematica 11.0...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to plot it correctly.'

```
distFunckappa = 
  Table[{v, (v^2 (v^2/(k - 3/2) + 1)^-k Gamma[k + 1])/(
    k Sqrt[\[Pi] (k - 3/2)] Gamma[k - 0.5])}, {v, 0, 10, 0.1}];

ListLogLogPlot[distFunckappa, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], AxesLabel -> {"v", "DNF"}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

This way you will get the correct plot. I really dont know, why simple loglog plot doesnt give 'the correct answer.

Comment: Would be nice if you explain why simple `LogLogPlot` does not give you the right result. As for now, you seems to indicate that only one of 2 functions should be used. However, many users (@Nasser) in the comments above have already indicated that they cannot reproduce you first picture, and that actually `LogLogPlot` gives the correct result. Also, you forgot the definition of `k` in your answer.

Comment: I clearly do not know, why simple loglogplot does not give a correct answer. This happens only in Mathematica 11.0. In Mathematica 11.1 the plot comes out correctly. Also the value of k is 2